# How to use SPEL along with regex in RequestMapping

Tags: regex, spring-mvc, spring-el

I have a controller method as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{fruitName:Mango|Orange|Grapes}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewFruit(ModelMap model, @PathVariable String fruitName) {
  ...
}
```

Here I am hard-coding **Mango, Orange and Grapes**, such that if url matches with any of these, then only this method should execute.

What I want to do is that, instead of hard-coding these fruits here. I want to declare them in a properties file and by using SPEL, I should bring it here.

Is this possible to do?

I tried code below for this, but failed with error:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{fruitName:#{fruit['seasonFruit.requestMapping']}}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewFruit(ModelMap model, @PathVariable String fruitName) {   
    ...
}
```

For following properties File (**fruit.properties**)

```
seasonFruit.requestMapping = Mango|Orange|Grapes
```

Please suggest, how this could be achieved?

Comment: No, it isn't possible. `@RequestMapping` doesn't support SpEL and property-placeholder resolutions.

Comment: @ArtemBilan So, isn't there any way by which we could achieve this? By separation of hard coding

Answer (score 3):

> @ArtemBilan So, isn't there any way by which we could achieve this? By separation of hard coding

Well, I hope you can do that from code:

```
@Value("#{ environment['seasonFruit.requestMapping'] }")
private String fruitName;

@RequestMapping(value = "/{fruitName:[a-z]", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewFruit(ModelMap model, @PathVariable String fruitName) {   
   if (fruitName.matches(this.fruitName))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may not be able to use combination of REGEX and values loaded from property files in requestMapping directly. But i am able to achieve in a sample app. Essentially i am resolving the entire regex pattern from property file, not just values of it. RequestMapping can resolve values from properties file.Hope this helps.

**Property file**

```
sample.test={url:mango|orange}
```

**Controller method:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/example/${sample.test}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testPattern(@PathVariable String url) {
        System.out.println("url:" + url);
        return sample;    
    }
```